# Formulario en C# que permita calcular el Total a pagar de 3 productos teniendo en cuenta que si lleva más de 3 productos obtiene un descuento

Tags: c#

[image: ALGO ASI]necesito ayuda lo mas pronto posible, tengo un ejercicio de la universidad y no he podido resolverlo, quisiera que me ayudaran, este el el enunciado

Elabore un formulario sencillo donde se permita calcular el Total a pagar de 3 productos teniendo en cuenta que si lleva  más de 3 productos  diferentes obtiene un descuento de 20%

tengo una leve idea de como desarrollarlo pero no he podido llegar a algo consiso, !!!NECESITO AYUDA¡¡¡

ALGO MAS O MENOS ASI.

Comment: y que fue lo que hiciste? El problema es muy simple, pero debes colocar tu codigo.\

Comment: no he escrito el codigo, solo diseñe el formulario y ya

Comment: te diria que es casi imposible tener un problema si no comenzaste, deberias tener que cuenta que elementos necesitas para comenzar como base.

Comment: tenes que agregar tu codigo, pero necesitas tener un array de productos, e ir cargando en este los productos, en un boton total podes calcular, recorriendo ese array, si el count es mas de 3 le aplicas el 20%.

Comment: Intenta hacer algo, porque la idea del sitio es ayudar en problemas, no solucionar tareas. En la facultad ya te deben haber dado los conocimientos necesarios para solucionar este problema, deberias usar todo lo aprendido

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ok, disculpen es que soy nuevo en stackoverflow

Comment: no hay problema, intenta hacer algo y tene en cuenta los elementos que te mencione, apenas te traves o no te sale algo, edita la pregunta y con gusto te ayudo. Mientras tanto modifica tu pantalla, coloca nombre de producto y precio, eso lo vas agregando en un array de producto, y en el boton calcular total recorres ese array para verificar y calcular.